# why embedded mongo process not stoping by mongodExecutable.stop()?

Tags: mongodb

Embedded mongo started successful with below code,,but not stoping by mongodExecutable.stop(),this suppose to stop the running mongo. what can be the issue,
The below code

```
 public class Test
       {
 private static final String CONNECTION_STRING = "mongodb://%s:%d";

    private static MongodExecutable mongodExecutable;
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    private static MongodProcess mongod = null;
   

    @After
   public void clean() {
        //mongodExecutable.stop();
        if(mongod.isProcessRunning()) {
        //mongod.stopInternal();
        mongodExecutable.stop();
    }}

    @Before
   public void setup() throws Exception {
        String ip = "localhost";
        int port = 27017;
        

        IMongodConfig mongodConfig = new MongodConfigBuilder().version(Version.Main.PRODUCTION)
            .net(new Net(ip, port, Network.localhostIsIPv6()))
            .build();

        MongodStarter starter = MongodStarter.getDefaultInstance();
        mongodExecutable = starter.prepare(mongodConfig);
        mongod=mongodExecutable.start();
    }

    @Test
    public void testfeature() throws Exception {
         assertEquals(1, 1);
       
        
    }
 }
```